# Get Portable KeySequence QString from shortcut in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I need to set shortcuts and then display them as text in a window. How do I set it using Windows-Style but retrieve the adapted key sequence depending on the OS?

For example, if I do something like this, I want to get Ctrl+O on Windows, and Cmd+O on MacOSX.

```
Window {
    visible: true

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        mouseArea.onClicked:
        {
            console.log(shortcut.sequence)
            console.log(shortcut.portableText)
        }
    }

    Shortcut
    {
      id: shortcut
      sequence:"Ctrl+O"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use [`QKeySequence`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html)?

Comment: Digging deeper I found _"QKeySequence isn't available as a type to QML."_ in a discussion about [Application wide shortcuts API for QML](http://development.qt-project.narkive.com/jCqPmjSR/application-wide-shortcuts-api-for-qml) but this is 4 years old. And this was the best matching I could find with google "qml qkeysequence" (on rank 43). So, this really seems to be tricky. (Or the existing solution is either so trivial or so secret that it's not mentioned in the everything-knowing internet.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was my conclusion too. I hope someone can come with a real obvious solution though;)

Comment: `QKeySequence::StandardKey` is available in QML as `StandardKey` ever since QML Shortcut was introduced. QML Shortcut offers `portableText` and `nativeText` properties that equal to `QKeySequence::toString(PortableText)` and `toString(NativeText)`, respectively. If these are not enough for your use case, I can't see how QKeySequence could help you any further. Or did I miss something?

Comment: I was actually needing the nativeText property, not the portableText one. I would swear I read the doc many times, but it was right in front of my eyes. Thanks!